# ASP.Net restart / GAC refresh

Tags: asp.net, iis

How should I "properly" restart the ASP.NET (IIS 5.1) server in order to refresh the loaded assemlies? I tried several things, but without success:

- tried to stop and start the web site in [IIS manager](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b0c14479-83e3-435d-a935-819fe396e7d2.mspx?mfr=true)
- [touched `web.config` file](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33638)
- [tried using `iisreset`](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/003ed2fe-6339-4919-b577-6aa965994a9b.mspx?mfr=true)
- tried to [kill ASP.NET processes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/01/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Command_2D00_line-Tasklist_2F00_Taskkill-Utilities-.aspx)
- my assemblies are **not** strongly-named, so they are not in GAC (checked using `gacutil` anyway)

Right now, every time I have a new version, I **publish** my site from the development machine, and then manually copy assemblies into the `/bin` folder - but I need to **restart** the server after every update in order to have my web site actually updated. Aspx pages update immediatelly (I can change them and see them update on-the-fly), but code-behind assemblies are not reloaded until I actually restart the machine.

To be sure of this, I am displaying the SVN revision number (hardcoded in my assembly during build time): `<% Response.Write(SvnInfo.CurrentRev); %>`

**[Edit]** Oooops - my mistake after all. It turns out that Publish command does not rebuild assemblies every time. I rebuilt the release version manually, published it, and it was running as soon as I copied assemblies to the `bin` folder.

Comment: Strange! Are you clearing the cache?

Comment: @Kangkan: Cache? Are you referring to GAC or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oooops - my mistake after all. It turns out that Publish command in Visual Studio does **not rebuild** assemblies every time.

I rebuilt the release version manually, published it, and it was running without problems as soon as I copied assemblies to the bin folder.